# How to parse a Java object which contains a list of a custom java POJO from REST Api call in component.ts file in angularJs

Tags: java, angular, rest

I am new to angular. I stuck to parse the response from the Java REST service to my angular UI.  I can see the expected list came from REST API call in Network tab of inspector but not able to parse it to my respective component.ts file in angular. I am getting Response is undefined in console log of UI. Below are the details
REST API Response Object

```
public FinalResponse(int statusCode, String statusMessage, Object objects) {
        super();
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
        this.objects = objects; // This Object holds the Array List of Persons Object 
    }
```

In My componet.ts file, I used below code

```
export class Person {
  constructor( public personId: number, public personName: string,){
  }
}

export class FinalResponse {
 
  constructor( public statusCode: number, public statusMessage: string, 
      public objects:any){

  }
}

export class PersonListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  persons: Person[]
  message: string
  finalResponse: FinalResponse


  constructor(private personDataService: PersonDataService, private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshPersonList();
  }

  refreshPersonList(){
    this.personsDataService.retrieveAllPersons().subscribe(
      response =>{
        console.log("Backend service response"+response)
        this.finalResponse =response;
        this.persons = this.finalResponse.objects
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.persons)
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.finalResponse.statusCode)
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.finalResponse.statusMessage)
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.finalResponse.objects)
      }
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Here I can see the status code & status message perfectly but am not able to see the List of Person object. In the UI console log, I can see it is undefined.
Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance, any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the console log of response

Comment: person-data.service.ts:1 Call through Http client personservice data service
person-list.component.ts:60 Backend service response1 undefined
person-list.component.ts:61 Backend service response[object Object]
person-list.component.ts:62 Backend service response1 200
person-list.component.ts:63 Backend service response1 Successfull
person-list.component.ts:64 Backend service response1 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
person-list.component.ts:65 Backend service response1 undefined

Comment: could you provide the function retrieveAllPersons in the component person-data.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

you are assinging wrongly from the response first.`data` keyword is needed for accessing the response data.
try this: `this.persons = this.finalResponse.data.objects`

Here it is:

```
this.personsDataService.retrieveAllPersons().subscribe(
      response =>{
        console.log("Backend service response"+response)
        this.finalResponse =response;
        this.persons = this.finalResponse.data.objects
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.persons)
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.finalResponse.statusCode)
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.finalResponse.statusMessage)
        console.log("Backend service response1 "+this.finalResponse.objects)
      }
    );
```

Comment: I tried this, But it is showing a compilation error Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FinalResponse'.ts(2339)

Comment: please console log the response and paste here

Comment: The number of object returning from REST API that is correct as per the data I have in DB

Comment: person-data.service.ts:Call through Http client personservice data service
person-list.component.ts:60 Backend service response1 undefined
person-list.component.ts:61 Backend service response[object Object]
person-list.component.ts:62 Backend service response1 200
person-list.component.ts:63 Backend service response1 Successfull
person-list.component.ts:64 Backend service response1 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
person-list.component.ts:65 Backend service response1 undefined

Comment: provide the code of `PersonDataService`